# Phenomenon of decreased improvement over time

Tags: probability

I was struggling to find a suitable stack to ask this questions, but I'm hoping that the answer is founded in maths.

I was wondering if there is a name or theory on the fact that if you do something a lot, the improvement rate goes down. For example, if you start working out you gain a lot of musscles in the first weeks, after that, the improvements will go down and it will get a lot harder to get the same improvements as in the first weeks.

So, is there a theorem supporting this in general, and what is it called?

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics.

Comment: "Law of diminishing returns" is a phrase that means something like this.  But as 5xum said, it's not mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "diminishing marginal returns" and is not a theorem or law, rather it is an assumption often made in economics. The mathematical statement of this idea is that a particular production function is *concave* (or the discrete analog).

It's important to stress that there is no law of nature ensuring that all production functions will have decreasing marginal returns. Many have *increasing* returns, especially at the low levels of production. Nonetheless, it is a common phenomenon and so is a property of interest.